# Crash at [ALAssetRepresentation metadata]

Tags: ios, ios7, exc-bad-access, alassetslibrary, alasset

My app uses ALAssetsLibrary to get all photos from the user's device and upload them to our cloud server. I notice that from time to time users get a crash at [ALAssetRepresentation metadata] (see crash log below). I cannot get the same problem at my device with any photos. Is it a problem with a system photo library? How can I prevent this crashing?

Thank you

```
Date/Time:           2014-08-16 10:15:39.865 +0300
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.1 (11D201)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000
Triggered by Thread:  9

....

Thread 9 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                     0x2eeda5c2 CFDataGetBytePtr + 6
1   PhotoLibraryServices               0x358d7128 __46-[PLManagedAsset adjustmentsXMPRepresentation]_block_invoke + 224
2   CoreData                           0x2ed839ca developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 86
3   CoreData                           0x2ed83b0e -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 110
4   PhotoLibraryServices               0x358d6fda -[PLManagedAsset adjustmentsXMPRepresentation] + 222
5   AssetsLibrary                      0x2e6f9498 __33-[ALAssetRepresentation metadata]_block_invoke + 20
6   AssetsLibrary                      0x2e700862 __53-[ALAssetRepresentationPrivate _performBlockAndWait:]_block_invoke + 66
7   CoreData                           0x2ed839ca developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 86
8   libdispatch.dylib                  0x39c2bd3c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
9   libdispatch.dylib                  0x39c306be _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 22
10  CoreData                           0x2ed83b06 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 102
11  AssetsLibrary                      0x2e6fc36a -[ALAssetsLibrary _performBlockAndWait:] + 130
12  AssetsLibrary                      0x2e700624 -[ALAssetRepresentationPrivate _performBlockAndWait:] + 172
13  AssetsLibrary                      0x2e6f93ec -[ALAssetRepresentation metadata] + 460
....
17  AssetsLibrary                      0x2e6fe70c __56-[ALAssetsLibrary assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:]_block_invoke_2 + 248
18  libdispatch.dylib                  0x39c2bd50 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
19  libdispatch.dylib                  0x39c31684 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 224
20  libdispatch.dylib                  0x39c318d8 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 52
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x39d5cc14 _pthread_wqthread + 296
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x39d5cad8 start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362294/crash-being-reported-for-alassetrepresentation-metadata-method